# Unable to install R package ranger

Tags: r, linux, gcc

I was trying to manually install package 'ranger' on SUSE 11. I'm using *sudo R CMD INSTALL ranger_0.8.0.tar.gz* in the console and after some compilations messages I receive the following error. Any workaround?

```
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/ranger/libs/ranger.so':
  /usr/lib64/R/library/ranger/libs/ranger.so: undefined symbol: __cxa_pure_virtual
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/ranger’
```

Additional details:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk"
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195014]
```

Comment: I would update R first since 3.1 is pretty old. If it still doesn't work ask again.

Comment: Do you know how can I install R 3.4.1 on Linux SUSE11 ? The latest supported is 3.1.3